# Java simple recursive algorithm, make it parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, executorservice, forkjoinpool

I have a simple recursive algorithm that generates all permutations of the string and counts a number of permutation which passes a few conditions. I would like to make it more efficient with parallel programming, but I am not able to use it with 'forkJoinPool' (I am not sure but it is not possible to make it with divide and conquer way). So I had and idea to run all computations (checking conditions and incrementing counter) on seprated threads, but It is not better than sequance algorithm.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
    compute(elements);
});
thread.start();
```

Code above doesn't seems to work better.

```
package com.company;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        call();
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((end - start) / 1000000);
    }

    private static void call() {
        char[] elements = "1234567890+/".toCharArray();
        Permutation p = new Permutation();
        p.printAllRecursive(elements.length, elements);
        System.out.println(p.counter);
    }
}


class Permutation {
    Integer counter = 0;

    public void printAllRecursive(int n, char[] elements) {
        if (n == 1) {
            // running compute() in parallel
            Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
                compute(elements);
            });
            thread.start();
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                printAllRecursive(n - 1, elements);
                if (n % 2 == 0) {
                    swap(elements, i, n - 1);
                } else {
                    swap(elements, 0, n - 1);
                }
            }
            printAllRecursive(n - 1, elements);
        }
    }

    private void swap(char[] elements, int a, int b) {
        char tmp = elements[a];
        elements[a] = elements[b];
        elements[b] = tmp;
    }

    private void compute(char[] elements) {
        String string = new String(elements);
        int index1 = string.indexOf('/');
        int index2 = string.indexOf('+');
        if (index1 > 0 && index2 > 0 && index1 < 11 && index2 < 11) {
            if (index1 > index2) {
                if (index1 - index2 != 1) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Method **compute(elements)** is time-consuming, how can I make it more efficient with multithreading?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want just a count or all the possible sets of the given String?

Comment: Yes, just counting

Comment: I don't think the problem is that compute(elements) is itself a taxing method it's that with a string of 12 chars long it's being called about 500,000,000 times

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `printAllRecursive()` you create an additional thread to call `compute()` and then call `printAllRecursive()` and create a new thread again.
The additional thread doesn't help you. **It seems that your algorithm is wrong**.

Look at the correct code to compute permutations:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        call();
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("time: " + (end - start) / 1000000);
    }

    private static void call() {
        char[] elements = "ABCD".toCharArray();
        int n = elements.length;
        Permutation p = new Permutation();
        p.printAllRecursive(elements, 0 , n-1);
        System.out.println("number of permutations: " + p.counter);
    }

}

class Permutation {
    Integer counter = 0;

    public void printAllRecursive(char[] elements, int l, int r) {
        if (l == r) {
            counter++;
            //System.out.println(String.valueOf(elements));
        } else {
            for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
                swap(elements, l, i);
                printAllRecursive(elements, l+1, r);
                swap(elements, l, i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void swap(char[] elements, int a, int b) {
        char tmp = elements[a];
        elements[a] = elements[b];
        elements[b] = tmp;
    }
}
```

You could see the illustration of this algorithm to better understand it, for example, [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/)

P.S. As I told before, your problem is not the multi-threading, but anyway I describe you why you cannot simply add the following code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
    compute(elements);
});
thread.start();
```

First thing that you should to realize is that you cannot modify the one area of memory by different threads.
In your code example you modify the field `counter` and the array `elements` from different threads.
Why you cannot modify one variable from different threads?
For example, a thread1 want to write into your array a sequence `'777777777'`
and during this writing process thread2 want to read values from array.
So, thread2 could read values `'777456789'`, because thread1 still writing data into array and havn't finish it yet.
So, we could change `Integer` by thread-safe `AtomicInteger` and add `synchronized` to signature of `swap` method.